# Invalid WQL Query on Win32_DiskDrive

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm playing around with WMI. I'm attempting to modify the code below to fix a bug, namely that it originally queried by model. If you had two drives with identical models, it would only return the \\.\PHYSICALDEVICE of the first disk. Instead, I am now presenting a \\PHYSICALDEVICE: MODEL string to the user. They select this from the drop-down, I parse out the physical device and use that for the query.

Except that I keep getting an error "invalid query" returned on the MOS query

```
 "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE DeviceID = '" + device + "'"
```

The query looks good to my eyes, but evidently isn't. Help appreciated.

Full code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Select item from drop down menu
        ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
"SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

        foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
        {
            string devid = moDisk["Model"].ToString();
            string drvnum = moDisk["DeviceID"].ToString();

            cmbHdd.Items.Add(drvnum + ": " + devid);
        }
    }

    private void cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //update form with selected device
        int i = cmbHdd.SelectedItem.ToString().IndexOf(':');
        string device = cmbHdd.SelectedItem.ToString();//.Substring(0,i);
        ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
"SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE DeviceID = '" + device + "'");
        foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
        {
            lblDeviceID.Text = "DeviceID: " + moDisk["DeviceID"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMI requires that backslashes (`\`) be doubled in queries.

Replace `\` with `\\` in the `device` variable before insetting it to the query and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. You've put me on the right path (I think). The device variable is already defined as `\\\\.\\PHYSICALDEVICE0`. Do I need to add more literal backslashes?

Comment: Yep - the var needs to be passed to the query as `\\\\\\\\.\\\\PHYSICALDEVICE0`. Madness. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidM: +1 for Madness. This is quite old, but still. You can partially return to sanity prefixing the string with @: @"\\\\.\\PHYSICALDEVICE0" should work.